# Restart a Unix service via a CGI script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a code to restart a Unix service via a Python CGI scripting. I am trying to with below options:

```
os.system("service tinyproxy restart")
exit_status = subprocess.call(["/usr/sbin/service", "tinyproxy", "restart"])
exit_status = sub.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', "/usr/sbin/service tinyproxy restart"], stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.STDOUT)
```

The issue with 1st option is that I am not sure if it was successfully restated or not. The second and third does not results me exit status as good i.e. 0. It returns me 1 - I am sure it is to deal with user / group issue as only root user can restart a Unix service.

How can I restart a Unix service via a Python CGI application?

Comment: One solution is to start a simple script with root, that will monitor a file, and restart the tinyproxy service when the file is changed. And then from the CGI app just do `touch /path/to/file`.

Comment: if it's a user issue, you can grant the user you are using to restart, rights via visudo

Comment: That would not be a good approach as it would un-necessary consume CPU for an event to occur

Comment: Granting rights would be a bit dangerous at level of system admin

Comment: well but it's impossible to execute a command you don't have rights for ... and you'd only need to grant restarting rights for tinyproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say grant your User restarting rights for tinyproxy:

add this line via visudo:

```
youruser ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/service tinyproxy start, /sbin/service tinyproxy stop, /sbin/service tinyproxy restart
```

and then your user should be able to execute this:

```
sudo /sbin/service tinyproxy restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be used:

```
import os
cmd1 = 'service tinyproxy restart'
os.system(cmd1)
```